# Hibernate (mysql) returns different results for same query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc, hql

I'm a little bit desperate right now because I'm sitting at this problem for about 2 days now :/

I want to query a list of users like so:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("FROM User as us WHERE us.allowedOnWebInterface = 1");
List webusers = query.list(); 
logger.info("Found " + webusers.size() + " users."); 
// i repeat the same query with jdbc via session.doWork and also log the result count
// do other stuff like load the webusers list into a var to have it available in the jsp
```

When i start my webapp locally i get the correct users displayed always.. BUUT when i deploy the war file of my webapp to a ubuntu server with jetty and also a mysql database then the application first shows me the correct users but when i edit or add a user then the application is confused.
If i refresh the user list page now i sometimes see all users i should see but sometime i just see a subset. I also get old results when i edited some users.

Taking a look into the log i can see that actually the same query gets different results, just by me refreshing the page.
Here's my logging output:

```
qtp569116871-17 2014-08-01 19:40:25,672 76978 INFO  query: FROM User as us WHERE us.allowedOnWebInterface = 1
qtp569116871-17 2014-08-01 19:40:25,684 76990 INFO  Found 6 users.
qtp569116871-17 2014-08-01 19:40:25,686 76992 INFO  with jdbc 5 results
qtp569116871-20 2014-08-01 19:40:33,419 84725 INFO  query: FROM User as us WHERE us.allowedOnWebInterface = 1
qtp569116871-20 2014-08-01 19:40:33,425 84731 INFO  Found 5 users.
qtp569116871-20 2014-08-01 19:40:33,434 84740 INFO  with jdbc 5 results
qtp569116871-17 2014-08-01 19:40:34,411 85717 INFO  query: FROM User as us WHERE us.allowedOnWebInterface = 1
qtp569116871-17 2014-08-01 19:40:34,420 85726 INFO  Found 5 users.
qtp569116871-17 2014-08-01 19:40:34,422 85728 INFO  with jdbc 6 results
qtp569116871-18 2014-08-01 19:40:35,114 86420 INFO  query: FROM User as us WHERE us.allowedOnWebInterface = 1
```

I also enabled mysql logging and checked the resulting mysql queries. They're all the same even tho different results are returned.
Maybe its also important to note that i use BoneCPConnectionProvider.

It would be nice if someone could help me with this

UPDATE:

It turned out that my problem was really caused by BoneCP. After commenting out all the BoneCp stuff in my hibernate.cfg.xml it finally worked without weird query answers from the database.

```
<!-- this is connection provider -->
<!--        <property name="connection.provider_class">com.jolbox.bonecp.provider.BoneCPConnectionProvider</property> -->

<!-- Database connection settings -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/mywebapp</property>
<property name="connection.username">hibernate</property>
<property name="connection.password">hibernate</property>

<!-- encoding -->
<property name="connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
<property name="connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
<property name="connection.useUnicode">true</property>

<!-- configure the bonecp conection provider -->
<!--        <property name="bonecp.partitionCount">3</property> -->
<!--        <property name="bonecp.maxConnectionsPerPartition">15</property> -->
<!--        <property name="bonecp.minConnectionsPerPartition">2</property> -->
<!--        <property name="bonecp.acquireIncrement">3</property> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

That's certainly odd and must be very frustrating. Things I would try to narrow down the issue:

1. Turn on jdbc logging using log4jdbc. See if there's anything different about the queries/results from the app side than what you're seeing via the mysql log.
2. Since there's only 6/5 users, write an extra log statement that iterates through the users and prints their IDs. Is it always the same user that's missing? What's up with that user record?
3. Perhaps you've got your caching configured wonky? Turn off the 2nd level cache:

   ```
   hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false
   ```

Also, make sure your query isn't being cached.

```
    query.setCacheable(false);
```